# Default Apache2 installation layout on Gentoo and LinuxMint installs

Tags: apache-2.2, gentoo, linuxmint

I have a perl website that I am trying to set up on my local LinuxMint install. All the configuration files are in the mercurial repository, however the layout for the Apache2 configuration in Gentoo (Live server) is quite different to that of LinuxMint (My Local)

for example:

Gentoo:

```
/etc/apache2/vhosts.d
/etc/apache2/modules.d
```

LinuxMint:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled
```

As well as the paths in the `httpd.conf` file and such are not quite the same and make it quite a bit harder to symlink the whole folder to that of the DVCS repo.

Is there a way to make the config directory in LinuxMint more like that of Gentoo? Like will Apache care if the whole folder structure is different, or is it really specifically tailored to the OS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure to replace everything, so you have the correct relations and such, apache should not really care.

What will happen though, is that commands like a2enmod and a2ensite on the Mint box will stop working. But since you pull the config from a repo I don't see that this should cause you much trouble.